# Quickbooks Online without PECL Oauth

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have a client in an hosting environment that will not allow him to install the PECL OAUTH package which is listed as a dependency. Is it possible that there are any simple modifications that will allow me to use some other OAUTH implementation to make the Quickbooks Online sdk work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the open source code from here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

No Pecl libraries necessary. Here's the quick-start guide:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start